# SQL select query fill null values based on the least closest non-null value

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following table (suppose the Name column is ascending):

```
Name    Tag
'a'     200
'b'     400
'c'     null
'd'     null
'e'     null
'f'     100
'g'     null
'h'     null
'i'     null
'j'     500
```

I want to write a `SELECT` query in Snowflake to return the null values with the least nearest value, like this:

```
Name    Tag
'a'     200
'b'     400
'c'     400
'd'     400
'e'     400
'f'     100
'g'     100
'h'     100
'i'     100
'j'     500
```

If I write the following query, it only fills the first null value for each consequent null group.

```
Select Name, coalesce(Tag, lag(Tag) over (order by Name)) as Tag
```

it returns:

```
Name    Tag
'a'     200
'b'     400
'c'     400
'd'     null
'e'     null
'f'     100
'g'     100
'h'     null
'i'     null
'j'     500
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snowflake supports the `IGNORE NULLS` clause: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lag.html

So, your query would be:

```
Select Name, tag as tag_original, coalesce(Tag, lag(Tag) IGNORE NULLS over (order by Name)) as Tag from tags;
```

Oracle supports `IGNORE NULLS` as well: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d108ff84755240ec3b488aed08d80dc5